# what is the name of bitset telling me?

Tags: c++, auto, bitset

Here is a trivial code snippet to give the name of auto date types. So then I was wondering what bitset would have for an identifier. it returns : "St6bitsetILm32EE". Ok, bitset is the datatype, 32 is the size, Im not sure what else the name is telling me. I don't know what St6, I, LM, or EE are referring to. Clarification would be nice.

```
// C++ program to demonstrate working of auto 
// and type inference 
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 
#define M 32  
int main() 
{ 
    auto x = 5;    //i for integer
    auto y = 3.37; //D for double
    auto ptr = &x; //Pi for pointer
    auto z = "WTF";//PKc for string or char**
    bitset <M> bset(2);
    auto k = bset; //bitset :: St6bitsetILm32EE  
     cout << typeid(x).name() << endl 
         << typeid(y).name() << endl 
         << typeid(k).name() << endl 
         << typeid(ptr).name() << endl 
         << typeid(z).name() << endl; 

    return 0; 
}
```

pardon my comments, I literally just learned about the auto datatype.

Comment: The string returned by `type_info::name()` is not expected to be human-readable; just unique for each type. The exact string is implementation-defined. Is there a reason you care?

Comment: bitset is that way because it is a proxy type that can be used to refer to a single bit. Single bits are not fundamental  types and they need extra info like offsets into the data type used to store them. The proxy type provides that mechanism. Oh, and z is a `const char*` not a `char **`  BTW, good way to learn stuff doing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Names in C++ are [mangled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

I am guessing the name has been mangled mangled according to [Itanium C++ ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangle.qualified-type) rules. The rules specify how each type/identifier/function name is mangled. From that you can try to manually demangle the type:

- `St` is `<substitution>`. It's used to compress `::std::` namespace prefix.
- `6` is `<number>`. It encodes then length of the following identifier. Next 6 characters make the identifier.
- `bitset` is `<identifier>`. It has 6 characters. It's the identifier of this class.
- `I` starts `<template-args>`. It it the list of template arguments.

  - Then follows one `<template-arg>`
  - `L` starts `<expr-primary>`.

    - `m` is `<type>`. This is the type of template argument, not it's value. `m` means the type is `unsigned long`.
    - `32` is the value passed as template parameter. `32` is not the size here.
  - `E` ends `<expr-primary>`.
- `E` ends `<template-args>`.

So `St6bitsetILm32EE` is a mangled name for type `::std::bitset<(unsigned long)32>`.

Comment: "The 6th substitution in `::std::`" — what does this mean? My reading is that 6 is the number of characters in the following identifier, `bitset`.

Comment: According to that document substitutions are followed by an optional number and an underscore unless they are in the hardcoded table, which says: `In addition, the following catalog of abbreviations of the form "Sx" are used:   <substitution> ::= St # ::std::   ...` so I don't think the number is part of the substitution or it would have shown `<seq-id>` somwehere in there.

Comment: @KamilCuk I'm not surprised - the document is really confusing.